# How to get WebLogic to process certain files as JSP

Tags: jsp, weblogic11g

I am migrating a java web application from OC4J to WebLogic 11g. The application contains the following servlet mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*_dyn.txt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This works in OC4J for two reasons:
- the servlet name "jsp" is automatically mapped to the JSP servlet
- OC4J accepts the pattern *_dyn.txt even though it does not conform with the servlet standard.

I discovered in WebLogic I can explicitly map the servlet name "jsp" to the JSP servlet by adding the following:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

This works if I use a standard URL pattern such as /dyn/* but not the non-standard URL pattern *_dyn.txt that was accepted by OC4J.

I have tried using Tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter to map it instead, but this results in an exception in the JSPServlet class.

My UrlRewriteFilter rule looks like this:

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
    <from>**/*_dyn.*</from>
    <run class="weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet" method="service" />
</rule>
```

The exception I get is this:

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error 
[AddToMap: pattern=/bla/test_dyn.txt class=jsp_servlet._bla.__test_dyn_txt]
    at weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:220)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run.invokeRunMethod(Run.java:416)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve my goal?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: $50 paypal credit for the first person who can tell me how to get this working. No payment for:  
- saying it is not possible or  
- solutions that involve redirecting to a file with a .jsp extension  
I desperately need a solution!

Comment: A suitable workaround has been found although it does not solve the exact problem. Instead of using the pattern *_dyn.txt I'm using *.dyn_txt and setting the HTTP Content-Disposition header to specify the desired name of the downloaded file with a .txt extension.